# PullRequestcontribute access needed error

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I am using custom task to create a pull request in release pipeline. But the task fails with error as below.

error:
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message": You need the Git 'PullRequestContribute' permission to perform this action.

whereas, I have correctly given access for pull request contribute in repository security permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to grant the Build Service user permissions for this to work.

Here's how:

1. Go to **Project Settings** and **Repositories**
2. **Select** the **Repository** you'd like to configure these permissions for
3. Go to **Security**
4. You should see **2** standard users if you have Azure Pipelines setup. (1. The admin who set up the organisation and 2. A build service user named as '[PROJECT NAME] Build Service ([ORGANISATION NAME])) **Example: 1. John Doe and 2. Business unit1 Build Service (MyBusiness)**
5. **Select** the **Build Service user** to change it's permissions
6. **Allow** the user to **Contribute**, **Contribute to pull requests**, **Create branch** (if necessary)

All done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As stated in [this github issue](https://github.com/shayki5/azure-devops-create-pr-task/issues/35#issuecomment-620904327), this could be caused by a misconfigured user at the repository level or at the organisation level. Here are the proposed solutions :

1. At the repository level :

> Go to the _project settings--> Repository--> select your branch in the list--> right side you will see the user and the newly created user under users. Allow "Contribute Pull Request" for the created user.

2. At the organisation level :

> Go to Organization *Settings-->under Security-->Permissions--> Project Collection Build Service Accounts-->Memebers-->Add -->Project Collection Build Service (xxxxxxxx)*

In my case the agents were not using the expected user (I defined another user in the  instead of using the Project Collection Build Service (xxxxxxxx) one). By adding the user at the organisation level (solution 2) I was able to fix the issue.

Hope it can help anyone that encounters the same problem.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. Try the other answer.